# Where is Directory Security in IIS

Tags: iis

I'm reading this [DOC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324069/how-to-set-up-an-https-service-in-iis) about IIS, and it mention `Directory Security`, but I'm using other language (not English) of IIS and I can't find it.

> 6. Click the Directory Security tab.

Can someone take a screenshot in English to show where it is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "This procedure assumes that your site has already has a certificate assigned to it." - Is your site running with a binding associated with a self-signed (or otherwise) certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the article it calls IIS as `Internet Service Manager`, and I found [HERE](http://www.thenetworkencyclopedia.com/entry/internet-services-manager/) said that this is the name of IIS in `Windows 2000`, which is quite old system.

Besides in the end of text it says `310178 How To Install Imported Certificates on a Web Server in Windows 2000`, indirectly show that it may be written in the windows 2000 age, so I guess this guide may not be suitable on my Win 7 IIS.

In Win 7 IIS there is SSL setting has similar function:

[image]